# How can I use a variable as a json key in karate?

Tags: json, bdd, karate

```
* def myvariable = 1 
* def schema =
"""
{
  myvariable : '#number',
  2: '#number',
  3: '#number',
  4: '#number',
  5: '#number',
  6: '#number',
}
"""
```

I need to use 'myvariable' as a key. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please eloborate your query with the analysis, So the others could  help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def schema = {}
* schema.myvariable = 1
* match schema == { myvariable: 1 }

# dynamic key name
* def name = 'myvariable'
* def schema = {}
* schema[name] = 1
* match schema == { myvariable: 1 }
```

Comment: Thans Peter, Your answer helped